# Parsing MML logs with python

Tags: python, algorithm, parsing, telecommunication

I would like to parse a text file to extract information into a spreadsheet program , the problem is that the input text file often has multiple seperators ,delimiters and text characters like below.

```
Script Task : dd_new
==========Summary==========
Success Num : 2690
Fail Num : 2342
===========================

==========Fail MML Command==========
MML Command-----LST RACHCFG:;
NE : 042249
Report : Ne is not connected.

MML Command-----LST RACHCFG:;
NE : 073196
Report : +++    073196        2016-08-11 16:01:00 DST
O&M    #22638
%%/*327033029*/LST RACHCFG:;%%
RETCODE = 939589973  Invalid Command.


---    END

MML Command-----LST RACHCFG:;
NE : 236263
Report : +++    236263        2016-08-11 16:00:59 DST
O&M    #807456706
%%/*325939762*/LST RACHCFG:;%%
RETCODE = 0  Operation succeeded.

Display RACHCfg
---------------
Local cell ID  Power ramping step(dB)  Preamble initial received target power(dBm)  Message size of select group A(bit)  PRACH Frequency Offset  Indication of PRACH Configuration Index  PRACH Configuration Index  Maximum number of preamble transmission  Timer for contention resolution(subframe)  Maximum number of Msg3 HARQ transmissions

1              2dB                     -104dBm                                      56bits                               6                       Not configure                            NULL                       10times                                  64                                         5                                        
2              2dB                     -104dBm                                      56bits                               6                       Not configure                            NULL                       10times                                  64                                         5                                        
3              2dB                     -104dBm                                      56bits                               6                       Not configure                            NULL                       10times                                  64                                         5                                        
(Number of results = 3)


---    END



MML Command-----LST RACHCFG:;
NE : 236264
Report : +++    236264        2016-08-11 16:01:00 DST
O&M    #807445026
%%/*325939772*/LST RACHCFG:;%%
RETCODE = 0  Operation succeeded.

Display RACHCfg
---------------
                              Local cell ID  =  1
                     Power ramping step(dB)  =  2dB
Preamble initial received target power(dBm)  =  -104dBm
        Message size of select group A(bit)  =  56bits
                     PRACH Frequency Offset  =  6
    Indication of PRACH Configuration Index  =  Not configure
                  PRACH Configuration Index  =  NULL
    Maximum number of preamble transmission  =  10times
  Timer for contention resolution(subframe)  =  64
  Maximum number of Msg3 HARQ transmissions  =  5
(Number of results = 1)


---    END
```

Approach:

The part where we split the line with a ":" as in line.split(':') is a clear way to build a dictionary ,but I need a way for the program to gnaw its way into making decisions all along the way.

- Is it a valid block ? (header Script task :dd new can be discarded).
- Fail MML commands with both NE not connected and Invalid command need to be extracted with the corresponding type into a dict : 
  {NE: '042249', Status : 'Ne is not connected'}, {NE :'07316', Status :  'Invalid Command'}
- Succesful MML command should be able to parse succesfully into a nested dictionary when either of the two output formatting of Display RACH Cfg are encountered .Both should yield (Nested Key value dictionary for each NE,Local cell id and then each parameter.

.

```
{NE:236263,{Local Cell Id: '1' : {Power ramping Step :'2dB',,Preamble initial received target power:-104dBm,........},Local Cell Id: '2' : {Power ramping Step :'2dB',,Preamble initial received target power:-104dBm,........}Local Cell Id: '3' : {Power ramping Step :'2dB',,Preamble initial received target power:-104dBm,........}
```

and a similar  (with a single Local Cell Id for the second case)

```
{NE :236264 ,{Local Cell Id : '1' { Power ramping Step :'2dB',Preamble initial received target power:-104dBm,.....}
```

I have searched the forums and seen examples of regex and ideas of replacing '===' with start /end tag and reading blocks but if there is a more pythonic way or an already existing library that deals with such stuff, it would make my life very easy.

For those who want to know what it is, these are MML logs from telecommunication equipment listing its configuration.

Comment: If you're using python, one approach is to find the grammar for MML logs and put that through PLY (a python parser generator). You can scrap data from the functions as you normally would. I cannot actually find this MML format you're talking about. Do you have any sources for examples?

Comment: There is no source that can be made available for you to fetch the data, i can share some .txt files, but they have the same content. Is that what you need?